# yii2 checkbox field dont'save data in db

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

i have a problem with the checkbox field that does not save me the data in the database . In the database I have the ' conditions ' field ( chekbox field ) as boolean . when sending the form I do not save as checked ( 1 ) .

**my model**
Rules

```html
return[
 'condizioniRequired' => ['conditions','required'],
            'condizioniType' => ['conditions','boolean'],];
```

**My view**

```html
<?= $form->field($model, 'conditions')->checkbox(array('label'=>'Offerted')); ?>
```

all other fields are saved.

Comment: have u getting post value of "conditions" after submitting form in controller?

Comment: the value is always 0 in the db after submitting and in controller i don't have create none function for 'conditions'

Comment: @Saba Try putting your full view code,full controller code and full model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do like this :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'conditions')->checkBox(['uncheck' => '0', 'checked' => '1'])->label('label'=>'Offerted') ?>
```

I hope this will help!!.

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'conditions')->checkbox(array('label'=>'Offerted')); ?> will do the same effect,this will post data as '0' when unchecked and '1' as checked.I think OP has got wrong in some other place

Comment: Work! Thank's so much.